# Passing multiple parameters (objects) from angular to spring/hilbernate

Tags: spring, angular, rest

Angular:

```
function(team, team) { return this.http.put('/api/tradeTeam/', team, 
     team2).map(res => res.json()); }
```

Spring/Hibernate

```
@RestController
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/tradeTeam/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)  
    public List<Team> TradeTeam(@RequestBody Team team, Team team2) {       
        return teamService.TradeTeam(team, team2);      
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My Service is set up correctly.
My error is:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Comment: for ``put`` request , the third parameter is of ``options`` . you are passing your parameter there which is wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `team2` as a third parameter for the `http.put` function, which is taken as `options` (not for `body` where you need it).

You should send something like that (and I think this will need some more work also on the backend)

```
function(team, team2) { 
    return this.http.put('/api/tradeTeam/', {teams: [team, team2]})
       .map(res => res.json()); 
}
```

See: [Angular HTTP Client Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request)